# What is the correct procedure to install a Drupal security patch?

Tags: drupal, patch

The back-end admin interface informs me that there is a new security patch for Drupal 6, but I can find any information about ho wto install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/14231

this should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This page on the Drupal site explains the steps for upgrading as well: [Introduction to upgrading](http://drupal.org/upgrade/tutorial-introduction)